# Print from mapped function in multiprocessing Pool on Windows

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-idle

I am trying to generate a printout from my mapped workers in Python and the following works when I run it on the command line in Linux, but it doesn't print out when using the IDLE Shell on Windows.

I get `outputs: [None, None, None]`, but none of the `input:` prints from the `simulate` function.

Any ideas why?

```
import multiprocessing

def simulate(input):
    print("input:", input)

inputs = [1, 2, 3]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        outputs = pool.map(simulate, inputs)
    print("outputs:", outputs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is in the IDLE doc section Running User code.

> By default, IDLE runs user code in a separate OS process rather than in the user interface process that runs the shell and editor.  In the execution process, it replaces sys.stdin, sys.stdout, and sys.stderr with objects that get input from and send output to the Shell window. The original values stored in sys.**stdin**, sys.**stdout**, and sys.**stderr** are not touched, but may be None.

...

> IDLE’s standard stream replacements are not inherited by subprocesses created in the execution process, whether directly by user code or by modules such as multiprocessing.  If such subprocess use input from sys.stdin or print or write to sys.stdout or sys.stderr, IDLE should be started in a command line window.  (On Windows, use python or py rather than pythonw or pyw.) The secondary subprocess will then be attached to that window for input and output.

I started IDLE in Windows Command Prompt with `py -m idlelib`.  Then I pasted your code into Editor and ran it.  The output in Command Prompt, from the new processes, after the command line, is

```
input: 1
input: 2
input: 3
```

IDLE's Shell shows the same as you got, `outputs: [None, None, None]`.